# Accelerating sum over permutations of matrix elements

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, summation, permutation

I am trying to short-cut the use of a `CoefficientArrays` call by manually calculating the resulting matrix of coefficients myself (this avoids using symbolic arrays and is therefore quicker). The calculation that I'd like to shortcut looks like $R\cdot X \cdot R^\mathrm{T} - X=0$ (where $X$ is symmetric): as an example, given a matrix
$$
X=\left(\begin{array}{c,c}
x[1,1] & x[1,2]\\
x[1,2] & x[2,2]
\end{array}\right)
$$
and automorphism matrix
$$
R=\left(\begin{array}{c,c}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right)
$$
the `CoefficientArrays` entry looks like
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c,c,c}
a^2-1 & 2 a b & b^2 \\
a c & b c + a d - 1 & b d \\
c^2 & 2 c d & d^2 - 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

The code I'm using to calculate this in Mathematica looks like

```
coeff[automorph_, xarray_] := Module[{subfunc, indexfn, permind},
   (*Get the unique matrix element IDs*)
   indexfn = (Level[#, {1}] & /@ (DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@xarray));
   (*Find all permutations of these elements*)
   permind = Map[Permutations[#] &, indexfn];
   (*Define a function that works for each row of the coefficient array matrix*)
   subfunc[indices_] := 
    Total /@ 
     Map[Map[(automorph[[indices[[1]], #[[1]]]] automorph[[indices[[2]], #[[2]]]]
           - DiscreteDelta[indices[[1]] - #[[1]], indices[[2]] - #[[2]]]) &, #] &, permind];
   (*Map over rows*)
   subfunc /@ indexfn
   ];
```

and is called like

```
coeff[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{x2[1, 1], x2[1, 2]}, {x2[1, 2], x2[2, 2]}}]
```

This works for small examples as here, but I am attempting to scale this up to higher-dimensional tensor $R$ and $X$ (e.g. $X_{ijk}R^i_{i'}R^j_{j'}R^k_{k'}-X_{i'j'k'}$) and it does not scale particularly well. Could anyone help with how to speed up this function (or come up with another way to calculate the result of `CoefficientArrays` more rapidly)?

Comment: Hi. In LaTeX you have a $3 \times 3$ matrix, but your code produces a $4 \times 4$ matrix, which I find confusing. Also, you write $RXR-X=0$, are you missing a transpose somewhere, and why do you write $=0$? Also, can you explain in words what the meaning of the $(i,j)$-th entry is supposed to be?

Comment: Apologies for a couple of typos: my understanding is that CoefficientArrays generates the coefficients of the parameters $x$ in the linear equation $g(x)=0$: I guess we could drop the 0 if that is implied? The resulting matrix $A$ is expected to mean that $A.\mathrm{vec}(X)=0$ (where $\mathrm{vec}(X)$ is `Flatten@X` in Mathematica-language) has the same set of solutions as the original $R\cdot X \cdot R^\mathrm{T}-X=0$, as you'd get from CoefficientArrays. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intro.** Given a matrix `mat`, the matrices of the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ... tensor power of `mat` are

```
KroneckerProduct[mat,mat]
KroneckerProduct[mat,mat,mat]
KroneckerProduct[mat,mat,mat,mat]
...
```

See `tensorPower` below.

Closely related to this, the powers of `mat` also act on the [symmetric tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor) spaces. To obtain a matrix for this, we just have to take `tensorPower` and pre- and post-multiply with appropriate matrices `symL` and `symR`.

**Code.**

```
(* rectangular, sparse matrices that satisfy symL.symR = 1 *)
symR[dim_,power_]:=symR[dim,power]=With[{X=Map[Sort,Tuples[Range[1,dim],power]]},
    With[{Y=MapIndexed[(#1->#2[[1]])&,DeleteDuplicates[X]]},
        SparseArray[MapIndexed[({#2[[1]],#1/.Y}->1)&,X]]]];
symL[dim_,power_]:=symL[dim,power]=Transpose[symR[dim,power]]//#/Map[Total,#]&;

(* tensor power *)
tensorPower[mat_?MatrixQ,power_]:=If[power==1,mat,KroneckerProduct@@ConstantArray[mat,power]];
symmetricTensorPower[mat_?MatrixQ,power_]:=With[{dims=Dimensions[mat]},
    symL[dims[[1]],power].tensorPower[mat,power].symR[dims[[2]],power]];
```

**Examples.**

```
symmetricTensorPower[{{a,b},{c,d}},2]
```

gives

[image]

To get the matrix OP has given, one just has to subtract the identity matrix, which is easy enough.

Similarly

```
symmetricTensorPower[{{a,b},{c,d}},3]
```

gives

[image]

**Comments.**

- There is some ambiguity in the choice of `symL` and `symR`, corresponding to the choice of a basis on the symmetric tensor product spaces. Different choices give [similar matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity). The choice I made is consistent with the example OP has provided.
- I have not done any timing, since I do not know which values of `dim` and `power` are relevant for OP. But the generation of the sparse matrices `symL` and `symR` should be negligible, and apart from that, the code relies on a single `KroneckerProduct` call.

---

**Memory considerations.** The dimension of the tensor product and the symmetric tensor products are, respectively,

```
tdim[dim_,power_]:=dim^power;
sdim[dim_,power_]:=Binomial[dim+power-1,power];
```

This means for example that `symR` is a sparse matrix of size `tdim x sdim`.

The code given in this answer first constructs a matrix of size `tdim x tdim` using `KroneckerProduct`, and then reduces it to size `sdim x sdim` by multiplying with `symL` and `symR`. This means that if `tdim` is much bigger than `sdim`, then this code will produce an intermediate object that is much bigger than the final object.

Here are two examples:

```
tdim[15,3]/sdim[15,3]
(* about 5 *)

tdim[15,6]/sdim[15,6]
(* about 300 *)
```

In the second case, `dim == 15` and `power == 6`, the overhead is very big.

**Comment.** The case `dim == 15` and `power == 6` mentioned by OP will be challenging regardless of the method. In fact

```
sdim[15,6]
(* 38760 *)
```

This means that in this case, the final matrix will have size `38760 x 38760` with entries that are order 6 polynomials in various symbols. That will take up a lot (!) of memory. Even if the entries of this matrix were simply floating point numbers, this matrix would require about 12 gigabytes. In the case of polynomials of order 6, it will be much more.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you - in my timings on small examples, with `dim=15` and `power=2` my method took 0.19s and 1.6MB memory; this approach took 0.11s and 8.7MB memory. With `dim=15` and `power=3` my method took 19s and 47MB; this method took 8.6s and 1.6GB. So there's definitely a memory cost: I'm hoping to get to `dim=15` and `power=6` which I think my workstation will struggle with. Do you have thoughts on how to reduce the memory cost? As `symL` and `symR` are very sparse it feels like it should be possible to only calculate the entries which will eventually be required?

Comment: Please see the edit. Your `dim == 15` and `power == 6` are much bigger than I anticipated. (Sure you need that? In symbolic form?) The code I given here will not directly work. One could try to split things into pieces and avoid large intermediate results. For example, use the `power == 3` result to get the `power == 6` result: Calculate `aux = symmetricTensorPower[mat,3]`, then `aux2 = KroneckerProduct[aux,aux]`, then `auxL.aux2.auxR` where `auxL` is "defined by" `symL[15,6] = auxL.symL[15,3]` or so. I have not tried, and even this will generate huge intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will try them out - the `R` matrix I'm using is not symbolic, but does need to be to high precision (working precision around 30): I'm finding the nullspace of the result of this calculation, and the precision is needed to avoid errors in that step. If a non-machine-precision method is out there to help with memory that would also be great (I tried Compile but that doesn't like non-machine-precision)

Comment: One can calculate the nullspace without constructing the matrix.I think you mean the nullspace of `symmetricTensorPower[mat,power]` minus identity, which is the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $1$ of `symmetricTensorPower[mat,power]`. Suppose `mat` is diagonalizable with eigenvectors $e_i$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ (possibly complex). Then a basis of eigenvectors of `symmetricTensorPower[mat,power]` is given by symmetrizing $e_{i_1}\otimes\cdots \otimes e_{i_{\text{power}}}$ with $i_1\leq i_2\leq \ldots\leq i_{\text{power}}$ which has eigenvalue $\lambda_{i_1}\cdots\lambda_{i_{\text{power}}}$.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into symmetrizing the tensor product of the eigenvectors of the underlying `mat` - accepting the answer given as solving the problem as stated!